# She can't sing AND/ OR dance

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, negation

1. She can't sing **or** dance.
2. She can't sing **and** dance.

I saw both sentences; I guess that they are whole negation and partial negation respectively.
However, I am not sure which of the action verbs is negative in the second example.

Comment: They can mean different things. "She can't sing and dance" with the right emphasis could indicate something like "walking and chewing gum at the same time"

Comment: Does (1) mean" She can't sing, and she can't dance either" ; (2) mean " She can sing, but she can't dance " ?

Comment: #1 is clear: she cannot do either one. #2 is ambiguous.

Comment: Are you sure #2 is ambiguous?

Comment: (2) could mean that she can't do both at the same time.

Comment: As Cascabel said, (2) is ambiguous. It would be unidiomatic to use _and_ rather than _or_ unless you were talking about doing both at once.

Comment: With a heavy stress on the _and_, it could mean "She can sing, can't she? You can't expect her to be able to dance as well!" But except for this, I think sentence 2 is simply wrong.

Comment: Note that there is a negative in the sentence. Take out the negative and you don't have any problem distinguishing _or_ and _and_.  The reason this happens is that negation interacts logically with conjunctions in a way called [DeMorgan's Laws](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).  These state (in English) that "Not (p and q) is equivalent to (Not p) or (Not q)", and that "Not (p or q) is equivalent to (Not p) and (Not q)". In other words, negation changes the sign, like algebra, but with conjunctions instead of numbers.

Comment: @JohnLawler, If you would give an answer directly instead of the comment( If you don't mind ), I won't hesitate to take your answer.  You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Sorry, _Profe_, but you cannot leave that  there as a _comment_...it is obvious you put some thought and time into it.

Comment: How about "nor" ? "Can neither sing nor dance" / "Can't sing nor dance"? The latter maybe a bit improper

Answer (score 1):

*From CoGEL p. 934 § **13.31***, **And in relation to or**

> Because *and* and *or* contrast with one another in meaning, *or* following a
> negative is in some respects equivalent to *and*. Thus:
>
> - He doesn't have long hair or wear jeans. [1]
>
> is logically equivalent to the combination of two negative statements
>
> - 'He doesn't have long hair AND He doesn't wear jeans'. [1b]

This equivalence follows strictly from the so called De Morgan's law of mathematical logic.

- [(NOT (A or B)] ↔ [(NOT A) and (NOT B)] (*equivalence, symbolized by "↔"*)

*Given that no ellipsis is used*, in other words, given that no distributivity in reverse is applied, the mathematical law is strictly valid in language (any language); I mean by that that "He doesn't have long hair AND He doesn't wear jeans" is not taken as identical to "He doesn't have long hair AND  wear jeans".

§ **13.31** goes on as follows (without too much detail, which I'll try to supply)

> Conversely:
>
> - He doesn't *(both)* have long hair *and* wear jeans. [2]
>
> is logically equivalent to the inclusive disjunction of two negative statements:
>
> - 'EITHER *He doesn't have long hair* OR *He doesn't wear jeans* (*or both*)'. [2b]

This equivalence follows again strictly from the De Morgan's law of mathematical logic, which is true for "and" as well as "or".

- [(NOT (A and B)] ↔ [(NOT A) or (NOT B)] (*equivalence, symbolized by "↔"*)

Thus, [2] (He doesn't *(both)* have long hair *and* wear jeans.), which we take as [1b] (He doesn't have long hair AND He doesn't wear jeans) because of the ellipsis that is matter of fact in language (but foreign to logic) appears to mean both [1] and [2b],

- He doesn't have long hair or wear jeans. [1]
- EITHER He doesn't have long hair OR He doesn't wear jeans (or both)'. [2b]

which is nonsense. The explanation is that the coordinator in [1] and [2] is within *the scope of  negation*; more precisely  in [1b] and [2] the linguistic distribution of the negation, which yields equivalent statements ([1b] and [2]), is not valid in logic.

{He doesn't have long hair} AND {He doesn't wear jeans}' [1b]

He doesn't *(both)* {have long hair *and* wear jeans}. [2]

§ **13.31** goes on as follows

> The reversal of meaning arises because in [1] and [2], the coordinator is within
> the scope of negation (cf 10.64).
>
> Hence *or* tends to replace *and* in contexts which we have called
> NONASSERTIVE (cf 2.53), and more generally in subordinate positions in the
> sentence:
>
> Soldiers who mutinied or deserted were punished by death.
> [= 'Soldiers who mutinied were punished by death, and soldiers who deserted were punished by death.']
> If we complain or demand compensation, nothing happens.
> [= 'If w'e complain nothing happens, and if we demand
> compensation nothing happens.']
> He is good at painting with watercolours or with oil paints.

It is this linguistic feature of taking  "He doesn't have long hair AND He doesn't wear jeans"  as identical to "He doesn't have long hair AND  wear jeans" which induces what CoGEL terms "in some respect an equivalence between *or* and *and*" and "the tendency for *and* to replace *or* in some  non-assertive context" (here essentially contexts involving negation).
This means that "She can't sing or dance." and "She can't sing and dance." can be taken as meaning the same thing.
I believe that "She can't sing and dance." can also mean "She can't do both at the same time".
In a context that makes that clear, if  the sentence is being  used as a reminder or as a repetition of the fact in a shortened form, I think the form is acceptable; otherwise it is ambiguous and shows bad style.

*For instance, such a dialog as the following would be acceptable*

— No, that's a fact, she can't read or write.
— You're telling me she can't read and write, yet, she is in a class where all children know how to read an write… How do you explain that?

Comment: The ambiguity (i.e., ambiguous in the sense that some English speakers will misunderstand the construction) LPH describes can be addressed by replacing not/or with neither/nor: "neither x nor y" always means `¬( x ∨ y )` (or equivalently, `¬x ∧ ¬y` ) .  If you've ever wondered why your English teacher was trying to convince you to use neither/nor, this mess might be why!

Answer (score 1):

English isn’t strictly logical.

In your example, “can’t” can be read as “is unable to” (like “cats can’t fly”) or “is not supposed to” (like “you can’t walk on the grass”), or even as a constraint on the other speaker (like “you can’t be serious”). In each case, though, the natural parsing for “and” is as a conjunction of the two items. However, this isn’t because “and” follows “can’t”.

Consider the following:

- You can’t come and go as you please.

Coming and going are mutually exclusive, so the intent is to place them in disjunction. The intent is not to prohibit the (empty) conjunction.

- You can’t eat your cake and have it still.

The intent is to disclaim the (simultaneous) conjunction.

- You can’t cook and not eat.

The intent is to object to both, occurring in sequence (eating is done after cooking).

There are other examples. Conjunctions are tricky because they can function in so many ways: sequencing (and = then), grouping (and = together with), and purpose (and = in order to), etc. “Or” and “and” are sometimes interchangeable, sometimes not.

- You can have tea and coffee. (You are allowed to choose one or the other, but it would be odd to serve a mixture of both in one cup.)

Unfortunately, disambiguation might require knowledge of how the specific terms are used.

Comment: As a native speaker, I find the sentence, "You can have tea and coffee." to be a bit odd. I wouldn't be surprised to hear it from a native speaker, but it would sound off.

Comment: @Brian The context would be something like a waitress talking about after-dinner beverages.

Comment: In that context, I'd find "You can have tea and coffee" to be odd.  I'd expect the reply to either be, "We have tea and coffee" or "You can have tea or coffee." Typically, I'd expect the reply to match my question (i.e., "What do you have?" / "We have" vs "What can I have" / "You can have"), but I wouldn't find it odd if they didn't match.

Comment: @Brian It’s pretty idiomatic. [Google searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+can+have+tea+and+coffee%22&rlz=1CDGOYI_enAU811AU811&oq=%22you+can+have+tea+and+coffee%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6856j0j7&hl=en-GB&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) aren’t definitive by any stretch, but some of the first few hits reflect the kind of context I was talking about, where “and” conveys choice instead of ‘comprehensive’ inclusion.